# Extracting fields from an Ajax request

Tags: jquery, json, ajax

I have the following Jquery Ajax request:

```
    function DoPaymentSearch() {
    var start,end;
    start=Date.now();
    var getQuotesSuccess = function(results){
    end=Date.now();

    alert(JSON.stringify(results));
    };

$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    url: 'https://a-quote-server.com/',
    data: JSON.stringify(quoteRequest),
    success: getQuotesSuccess,
    dataType: 'json',
    processData : 'false',
    crossDomain : true
    });
}

$(document).ready(DoPaymentSearch);
```

which gives a JSON string which looks something like this:

```
{"VehicleResults":[{"Id":"0","FinanceProductResults":[{"Term":48,"AnnualMileage":10000,"Deposits":1000,"ProductResults":[{"Key":"HP","Payment":358.9},{"Key":"PCP","Payment":267.53}]}]}]}
```

However, I am having difficulty extracting the HP and PCP Payment fields from this. I'd like to append them to some text on the page.

Replacing the alert with:

```
$('#content').append(results.VehicleResults.FinanceProductResults.ProductResults.Key.HP.Payment);
```

Isn't working.

Comment: But you have JSON.parse the string before or?

Comment: @claus-bönnhoff If I try `var p = JSON.parse(results);` I get: Unexpected identifier "object"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `ProductResults` is *JSON Array* so to get all values from that array you need to iterate through it using some loop.

***Demo Code*** :

```js
var results = {
  "VehicleResults": [{
    "Id": "0",
    "FinanceProductResults": [{
      "Term": 48,
      "AnnualMileage": 10000,
      "Deposits": 1000,
      "ProductResults": [{
        "Key": "HP",
        "Payment": 358.9
      }, {
        "Key": "PCP",
        "Payment": 267.53
      }]
    }]
  }]
}
//if only first one to fetch
/*$('#content').append(results.VehicleResults[0].FinanceProductResults[0].ProductResults[0].Key);
$('#content').append(results.VehicleResults[0].FinanceProductResults[0].ProductResults[0].Payment);*/

//if all values from `ProductResults` need to be fetch
$(results.VehicleResults).each(function(i, value) {
  console.log(value.Id)
  $(value.FinanceProductResults).each(function(i, values) {
    console.log(values.Term)
    $(values.ProductResults).each(function(i, val) {
      $('#content').append("<p> Key : " + val.Key + " | Payment :" + val.Payment + "</p>")
    })
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="content">
</div>
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thank you so much.